# How do I call an API from HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to call my API for which is for database checking by the way from HTML such that when I click the button, it will call the API which then checks with the database for the correct results and output accordingly. So far, I am not entirely sure of the way to do this and have tried this

```
<div id="login">   
      <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

      <form action="http://localhost:3000/api/login" method="post">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
         Username<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="userID"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="Password"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <p><button class="button button-block">Log In</button></p>

      </form>

 </div>
```

Do note that this is only for login in checking database as to whether that user and password exists. It is just a testing for my project. In my js file,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/login",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data": "{\n\t\"userID\" : \"John\",\n\t\"Password\": 
  \"Password\"\n}"
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    });
 });
});
```

I have tried using AJAX but it kept redirecting back to home page so I decided to try putting the `<form action="http://localhost:3000/api/login" method="post">` to see if it would check against the database but it keeps giving a wrong output although it should be correct because its inside the database. Do tell me if you need more details in any way. Any help is appreciated! Do note that this is not for authenticating just for experimenting.

Comment: `$("p").click(...)`? No. Bind the click handler to the button. If you want to use Ajax then you don't want the form to submit so you need to either cancel the button's default behaviour or add `type="button"` to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an id in the form and also name and id for individual controls.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/api/login" id="loginform">
      <input type="userID" id="userID" name="userID" required autocomplete="off"/>
      .....
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Jquery code.
Replace `postvaruid` and `postvarpwd` with actual server parameters.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        // Set form variable
        var form = $('#loginform');           

        form.submit(function(event){              
          var userid = $('#userID').val(); 
          var password = $('#password').val(); 

          if ( $.trim(username) != '' && $.trim(password) != '') {
            // Process AJAX request
            $.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login',
                   {postvaruid: userid, postvarpwd: password }, function(data){
             console.log(data);
            });
          }              
          // Prevent default form action
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      });
```

### EDIT:

See [**this**](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) to understand the form submit callback function

What I wrote is similar to

```
$("#formid").submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

[**$.post**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) actually fires a http post request to server.

It's a shorthand ajax call equivalent to below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",  <---Note this
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Hi may I know what is the `function(event)` for and if`$post.(..)` is needed for all ajax requests`                                                          as well as                                                                                                  `<...action="http://localhost:3000/api/login"` when calling an api from html. I managed to get the correct output but I do not really understand your code in the parts I indicated.

Comment: As well as `input type= "userID"`because I was not able to find it in w3wschools.com so does this depend on your fields in any kind of words?

Comment: Does that mean `dataType`does not need to be declared or is there a default for it ? Just curious but is the `click(function()` possible for this as well or is it more complex for something like form submitting?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add an event listener to listen when it has been submitted.

```
document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener('submit', login);

function login() {
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
}
}
```

However. Make sure the data your are passing to the api is beeing processed the right way so it can be validated.
Guess your api expects some data, passed to the function as a parameter, inout fields must have name attribute value as the corresponding params in your code.
If yor behind code is like:

```
 function login(string user, string userpswd) {
    // Code here...
}
```

Then your HTML should be something like:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="userpswd" requiered="required" />
 </form>
```

As an example.

Comment: I know there's no "jQuery" tag on the question, but the OP is clearly using jQuery so why not `$("#loginForm").on("submit"...)`? You'd also need to call `event.preventDefault()`.